# Can I Include a URL Link Within a Chunk of Code in a Github Markdown Document?

Tags: url, github, markdown, code-formatting, github-flavored-markdown

I'm looking to propose some small tweaks/improvements to my employer's coding standard written in Github markdown (*.md).

I've prepped by reviewing a couple of references this markdown language's formatting conventions.

From my readings I see that I can add URLs in at least two different ways:

- Standard HTML:
  `<a href="LINK_URL">TEXT</a>`
- Markdown style links:
  `[TEXT](LINK_URL)`

...and code markdown is written as:

- Markdown style:

  ```` ```LANGUAGE
  MY CODE;
  ``` ````
- Implicit code denotation via 4 space indent.

However, I've been unable to find a reference on whether you can include a hyperlink inside a block of code (i.e. to the location of that object's source in your repository).

i.e. I want to do something like:

````
```javascript
_myQObject: <a title="QML Source for MyQObject" href="URL_TO_SOURCE">MyQObject {}
```
````

That does not work, however, and I've been unable to find documentation explicitly stating whether this is possible or not.

How can I include a link to a URL within a chunk of formatted Github markdown?

Is this possible?

For reference the basic style guides I've reviewed are:

- [Github Guides: "Mastering Markdown"](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)
- [Adam-P's "Markdown Cheatsheet"](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I include a link to a URL within a chunk of formatted Github markdown?

As far as I know this is not possible.

The [original Markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) [says](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode):

> With a code span, ampersands and angle brackets are encoded as HTML entities automatically, which makes it easy to include example HTML tags.
>
> …
>
> Regular Markdown syntax is not processed within code blocks. E.g., asterisks are just literal asterisks within a code block. This means it’s also easy to use Markdown to write about Markdown’s own syntax.

I haven't seen anything in the GitHub Markdown docs to suggest that they have added support for links in code blocks, and nothing I've tried has worked.

I also haven't seen this feature in any other Markdown implementations.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate... I'll just use my fall through which is to place a label with the file name linked above the block of code.  Thanks, Chris.  Please update this solution if they ever do implement this!

Comment: It's almost a rule of Markdown that some variant of Markdown breaks the rule. In this case, Stack Exchange [allows you to put a link into blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114095/markdown-syntax-for-link-inside-pre-block), if you ask nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late reply, but for people who come here hoping for a solution, there is a way to add links inside preformatted blocks. If you use an [HTML block](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks) with `<pre> ... </pre>` *instead* of using the code block formatting sequence (i.e., don't use [fenced code blocks](https://github.github.com/gfm/#fenced-code-blocks) or [indented code blocks](https://github.github.com/gfm/#indented-code-blocks)), you can then use `<a>` elements inside the preformatted text block. E.g.

```
<pre>
  myQObject: <a href="URL_TO_SOURCE">MyQObject {}</a>
</pre>
```

You lose the automatic syntax highlighting provided by "proper" code blocks, so there is a tradeoff.